# I can't install PHP

Tags: php

I can't get PHP to work on my mac - any time I run it, it just appears as text.

I checked Terminal to see if PHP was installed (I ran: `php -v`) and it does seem to be; it says:

> PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2016 21:36:17)  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies.

I've also un-commented this line: `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in `httpd.conf`. However, none of these steps seem to do anything. I've also looked through other questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them help, either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you adding `<?php` at the beginning of each file?

Comment: did youz run a2enmod php5 ?

Comment: sry about that (that was another part of my php installtion which only indirectly was connected to php)

Comment: _It's **2019**_. [PHP 5.4 hasn't been supported for 3.5 years](https://serverfault.com/a/713684/374091). For the love of all you hold dear, please use _**at least**_ version 7.2 and ideally 7.3. You can see [which versions are supported on the PHP website](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try installing a later version.

Comment: install with brew ... please.  Also, after install, do add /usr/local/bin to your path. Finally, you need to have a ` AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` line in the mime types section of your httpd.conf